# How to show more data under title in event card , React-big-calender

Tags: reactjs, calendar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a859w.png) There is the image of my event, I have to add more information in that event card under event title

Answer (score 0):

if i'm correctly u are using [react-big-calender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-big-calendar) and you can add [components](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-components) to your calender.
so if you add the component "day: event" you can edit the event style/text and add more info

```
components={{
    day: {
        event: (props) => <div>info</div>,
    },
}}
```